# error CS1012: Too many characters in character literal - why it sometimes compile and sometimes not

Tags: c#, launchpad

I have this code:

```
this.lentry2.InvisibleChar = '●';
```

it compiles perfectly everywhere, except for ubuntu's launchpad. When I am building this in there I am receiving this `CS1012` error. Why does it work on any of my own PC's but not on launchpad? Is that character really not "supported" by c# so I am just lucky that it works on my own PC, or is there something wrong on launchpad?

here is a log: https://launchpadlibrarian.net/170375518/buildlog_ubuntu-precise-amd64.pidgeon_1.2.6.0ppa1.1ubuntu1_FAILEDTOBUILD.txt.gz

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's all to do with the character encoding the compiler is using to convert your file into text.

You can specify this in the `mcs` command line with the `-codepage` parameter. (Or `/codepage` in `csc`.)

Alternatively, to make it easier to get this right everywhere, keep all your source code in ASCII and use a Unicode escape sequence in the character literal, e.g.

```
this.lentry2.InvisibleChar = '\u25CF';
```

Comment: TBH this code was generated by monodevelop (it has some visual editor of GTK forms). Maybe I could report it as a bug then? If this code is better it should be probably generated by monodevelop as well.

Comment: Trying your code, it returns error CS1009: Unrecognized escape sequence `\2'. I did use exactly that line as you posted it.